# Adding a new Scintilla Lexer to Geany

Tags: lexer, file-type, scintilla, geany

I wrote a new lexer for a custom Language in Scintilla. I followed both [scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html) and [geany documentation](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html) along with [hacking geany](http://geany.org/manual/dev/hacking.html).

However geany does not recognize my language. I also implement filetype for it but still it does not seem among `Document->Set Filetypes`.

To be more precise assume you have such a [lexer](https://bitbucket.org/StarFire/scintilla-doc/downloads/Scintilla-var'aq-Tutorial.pdf) . What must be procedure to follow for finding this language among `Document->Set Filetypes`.

Comment: You will need to provide full diff to Geany core as without searching for error is just guessing. Also 'd recommend to ask this on geany-devel mailinglist rather than here. Check http://www.geany.org/Support/MailingList#devel

Comment: What you mean by full diff?

Comment: You changes done: Lexxer, makefile, Geany filedefs etc.

Comment: Yes i think , but maybe some small thing left

Comment: Without providing what you have done, debugging what you might have missed is very hard.